# Laravel validation rule fails when trying to update the same record with no changes

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-validation, laravel-formrequest

I've got a table called `Sides` which consists of `id`, `name`, `side_category_id` and some other fields not important at the moment.

I wanted to validate that when creating a new `side` record, the record doesn't exist already. So, let's say I've got in the database a record such as:

```
id: 1
name: Salad
side_category_id: 3
```

If I try to insert a new record with `name = 'salad'` and `side_category_id = 3` then the creation must fail and return an error.

I've achieved this by using the following rule:

```
$rules = [
   'name'             => 'required',
   'side_category_id' => 'required|exists:side_categories,id|unique:sides,side_category_id,NULL,id,name,' . $this->request->get('name')
]
```

So far so good. It works as it's supposed to. But now it's returning an error if I want to edit a record and save it without any modifications and this is not my desired outcome.

If I try to update the record with no modifications it should succeed. How can I update my rule to achieve this?

Comment: You have to pass the id of the record to ignore after a comma to the unique rule  `'side_category_id' => '....|unique:sides,side_category_id,' . $this->request->get('id')`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I just tried it but didn't work. Still getting the same error saying: The side category id has already been taken.

Comment: Are you receiving the record id in the request or as route parameter? If it's a route parameter an you get it as function arg like `public function update(Request $request, $id)` you should use the `$id` variable.  `'...|unique:sides,side_category_id,' . $id` or if you are using model binding like `public function update(Request $request, Model $model)` you should use `'....|unique:sides,side_category_id,' . $model->id`

Comment: Yes, I'm receiving the id as route parameter. I've updated my rule to `...|unique:sides,side_category_id,' . $this->route('id')` but the same error keeps popping up. (Didn't use `$id` directly because it says it's not defined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **Rule::unique()**

for **create** use like this

```
$rules = [
   'name'             => ['required'],
   'side_category_id' => ['required',Rule::unique('sides', 'name')->where(function ($query) use($category_id) {
    return $query->where('side_category_id', $category_id);
}),Rule::exists('side_categories')]
]
```

for **update**

```
$rules = [
       'name'             => ['required'],
       'side_category_id' => ['required',Rule::unique('sides', 'name')->where(function ($query) use($category_id) {
        return $query->where('side_category_id', $category_id);
    })->ignore($id),Rule::exists('side_categories')]
    ]
//$id should be you parameter
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this but I'm not super happy having two separate `FormRequest`, I'd rather have one if possible since basically the same operation (store) is being executed

Comment: you you can use second rule for **create and update** when you update you have to pass object id as **request** param change `->ignore($id)` to `->ignore($this->id)`